# How can I construct a Vertica insert statement without adding column name like using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vertica

I create a `Vertica` table likes this:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
( 
ID AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, 
Name VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '', 
City VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

I know "`insert into test(Name, City) values('Nan', 'Nanjing')`" can insert record successfully.

But when using `MySQL`, I can use this statement to insert a record: "`insert into db.test values(NULL, "Nan", "Nanjing")`". While this statement can't work in `Vertica`.

So is it possible to construct a insert statement without adding column name like `MySQL`? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Postgres, Vertica uses the keyword `DEFAULT` for default values.  So you can do:

```
insert into test
    values (DEFAULT, 'Nan', 'Nanjing');
```

However, I think it is best practice to include the column names explicitly.

Comment: So for "`insert into db.test values(NULL, "Nan", "Nanjing")`" statement, using `NULL` value will works correctly for auto increment column in MySQL. Is this a specific only for MySQL, not universal?

Comment: @NanXiao . . . I think it is specific to MySQL.  To be honest, with very, very few exceptions, I *always* use explicit column lists so this isn't functionality that I keep close track of between databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Out of curiosity, what experience do you have with Vertica?

Comment: @kermit . . . A limited amount specifically with Vertica, but it is one of many Postgres-derived databases out there.